# Agarose vs agar? Why do DNA gels use agarose only and how do you obtain agarose from agar?

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-reagents

[Agar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar) is a relatively cheap substance from red algae.  And it contains a saccharide agarose as well as a small amount of pectin.

Agar is used for culture plates as is, but for DNA gels a grade of agarose, I guess with the pectin removed.  What happens when a gel is run in agar?  i.e. why remove the pectin?

If you can guess, how is the pectin removed?  I know there are [enzymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectin_lyase) that might do it, but not sure what's really used.

Comment: @dd3 has put down a great answer - esp with the figures in the answer!  Would love to see an answer to what the industrial process is like.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar):

> Agar is a heterogeneous mixture of two classes of polysaccharide:
>   agaropectin and agarose. Although both polysaccharide classes
>   share the same galactose-based backbone, agaropectin is heavily
>   modified with acidic side-groups, such as sulfate and pyruvate. The
>   neutral charge and lower degree of chemical complexity of agarose make
>   it less likely to interact with biomolecules, and, therefore, agarose
>   has become the preferred matrix for work with proteins and nucleic
>   acids.

This [page](http://citizensciencequarterly.com/2012/01/30/cheapass-science-comparison-of-agarose-agar-agar-and-cleaned-agar-agar-for-gel-electrophoresis-of-dna/) compares the result of using agar gels to that of using agarose:
[image]

The second part of your question: here's a [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US4990611), although I have no idea whether this method of agarose purification is widespread.  Propylene glycol purification of agarose does seem to pop up a lot.  I think people who  purify their own agarose use that method, but I am not sure if biotech companies have other methods.

EDIT: it's propylene glycol, followed by ethylene glycol, that is commonly used, but PEG has been used [at least once](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/31965/0000007.pdf).

Comment: thanks for doing this answer!  I looked at similar patents after looking at the one you are pointing to and as late as 1987 they are precipitating agarose with glycols or PEGs... looks good!

Comment: You're welcome. It was a good question, and I enjoyed finding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using DMSO (dimethyl sulfoxide), agarose can be separated. After heating and stirring around 2 hrs you will get a yellow stiff gel of agarose by filtering.

Comment: this is cool! have a recipe?  I'd like to try this!

Comment: @shigeta: here is a [paper](http://testj.kofst.or.kr/Upload/files/TEST/08You-Jin%20Jeon-%EC%98%A4.pdf)